# preg_match_all to return pattern matches rather than subject matches

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to return the matches from a string as below:

```
$subject = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";
$pattern = "/(Dog|Brown|Fox)/i";
$pregMatchCount = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

However, because of the case insensitive modifier, this returns an Array something like the below:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => dog
        [1] => brown
        [2] => fox
    )
```

The case insensitive modifier is important, as the pattern will be dynamically generated. There are other ways around this, however it would be better (and more efficient) if there was a way to catch the pattern matches in this instance, like below:

```
Array
    (
        [0] => Dog
        [1] => Brown
        [2] => Fox
    )
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'd have to clarify how you're dynamically generating the regex patterns in order to have us figure out a way to track back to the original regex string that you're providing.

Comment: Hey FrankerZ. So the regex pattern is loaded from an xml feed, which is subject to frequent change. Further on in the application, I'm going to want to find that item again within the feed (using an xpath query). There's definitely something I can do at that stage to fix the issue, however it would be preferential to solve this within the preg match if possible. If theres no solution within the preg match i'm going to have to look at the second option.

Comment: Is it complex regex, or just like an delimited list of items to search for?

Comment: That's not possible. Your pattern isn't `Dog` or `Brown` or `Fox`. So even if the regex engine returned the match group, it would still be `"Dog|Brown|Fox"`. Only workaround is to use `(?<named>` capture groups to preserve a relation, or post-process/map the result.

Comment: it's a delimited list, as shown in the example

Comment: Can you give me the exact string that you're getting from the XML feed? Is it "(Dog|Brown|Fox)", or "Dog|Brown|Fox", or "Dog,Brown,Fox", or something else?

Comment: The XML feed has a dozen items in (won't list for simplicity's sake). The script runs through the feed and takes each item "Dog" "Brown" and "Fox" as individual entities, and then prepares them for the regex by concatenating with delimiters. Does that make sense?

Comment: Iterate over each term and check if it is in the string, if it is output the version you want. You can't capture the title case version because it isn't in the string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the original answer, *although it solves the sample problem stated by the OP*, doesn't address the primary question formulated in the title.

*Imagine someone desperately looking for an answer to this/some problem up, finding this page on Stack Overflow... and the answer wouldn't address the original problem stated in the title but would be an "alternative solution" to the possibly isolated and thus reduced problem.*

Anyway...

This is how I would go about this.

```
<?php

$subject = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

$needles = [
    'Dog',
    'Clown',
    'Brown',
    'Fox',
    'Dude',
];

// Optional: If you want to search for the needles as they are,
// literally, let's escape possible control characters.
$needles = array_map('preg_quote', $needles);

// Build our regular expression with matching groups which we can then evaluate.
$pattern = sprintf("#(%s)#i", implode(')|(', $needles));

// In this case the result regexp. would be:
// #(Dog)|(Clown)|(Brown)|(Fox)|(Dude)#i

// So let's match it!
$pregMatchCount = preg_match_all($pattern, $subject, $m);

// Get rid of the first item as it represents all matches.
array_shift($m);

// Go through each of the matched sub-groups...
foreach ($m as $i => $group) {

    // ...and if this sub-group is not empty, we know that the needle
    // with the index of this sub-group is present in the results.
    if (array_filter($group)) {
        $foundNeedles[] = $needles[$i];
    }

}

print_r($foundNeedles);
```

The result being:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Dog
    [1] => Brown
    [2] => Fox
)
```

Comment: You may want to pass the array of `$needles` to [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) to prevent preg_match warnings if the needles contain special characters (`. \ + * ? [ ^ ] $ ( ) { } = ! < > | : -`)

Comment: Yes, you're quite correct. I, without any basis, assumed that the array of needles would consist of mere words. I'll add it to the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend not using regex for this task, as it's not needed. Simply use [`stripos()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.stripos.php) to figure out if an item is in a string.

```
function findMatches($subject, $items)
{
    $matches = array();
    foreach ( $items as $item )
    {
        if ( stripos($subject, $item) !== false )
        {
            $matches[] = $item;
        }
    }

    return $matches;
}

$subject = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";

print_r(findMatches($subject, array('Dog', 'Brown', 'Fx')));
```

See [this fiddle](https://3v4l.org/CoSSd) for a demo/performance stats.

You could also do a simply array_filter:

```
$subject = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog";


print_r(array_filter(array('Dog', 'Brown', 'Fx'), function($item) use ($subject) {
     return stripos($subject, $item) !== false;
}));
```

Comment: I agree this would work, as i originally stated, i know there other ways around this. However, i'm going to be using multiple feeds, all which have different structures, and therefore preparing a regex of 200 items is surely easier than your example?

Comment: I feel like formatting it to regex is going to be worse then just iterating over the list of items you already have. It's also going to make the code look clunky, and isn't going to perform as well. Also: What you're saying isn't possible, without some decent workarounds.

Comment: Your answer doesn't include repeated matched patterns to final array.